# Falha ao efetuar push - Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android-studio, git, github

Atualizei meu Android Studio para a versão 3.0, mas agora que fui efetuar o *push* no meu *app*, ele apresentou o seguinte erro, já tentei de todas as maneiras e não consigo efetuar tal ação:

> Unable to access 'https://github.com/jaelson13/epymaps.git/': could not resolve host: github.com

Comment: Tem um proxy na sua rede?

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, não possuo nenhum proxy em minha rede.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível que tenha configurado por engano o uso de proxy pelo git e ele não consiga resolver o github.com.

Experimente desabilitar as configurações de proxy do git, executando na linha de comando:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder o tópico, acabei formatando o PC e voltou a funcionar.